# Static resource not found in static content provider for published binary

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa2.2, sites-9.6

We have upgraded from SDL Web 8.5 to Tridion Sites 9.6 and using dxa java 2.2.3 . We are encountring a strange issue while fetching published binary from broker database dxa is giving below error however the binary is published in broker database

```
[![16:01:01.464 \[http-nio-9012-exec-3\] WARN  c.s.w.c.i.i.StaticContentInterceptor - Static resource not found in static content provider for /en/images/137005-e346c079-2fdc-438b-8403-e8abd3da82c0.json. Fallback to webapp content...
com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.StaticContentNotFoundException: No binary found for pubId: \[10\] and urlPath: http://192.168.125.102:9012/en/images/137005-e346c079-2fdc-438b-8403-e8abd3da82c0.json
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.content.GraphQLStaticContentResolver.processBinaryComponent(GraphQLStaticContentResolver.java:150)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.content.GraphQLStaticContentResolver.createStaticContentItem(GraphQLStaticContentResolver.java:85)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.content.GenericStaticContentResolver.getStaticContentFileByPath(GenericStaticContentResolver.java:83)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.content.GenericStaticContentResolver.getStaticContent(GenericStaticContentResolver.java:41)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.GraphQLContentProvider.getStaticContent(GraphQLContentProvider.java:171)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor100.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.getStaticContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.interceptor.StaticContentInterceptor.preHandle(StaticContentInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.interceptor.StaticContentInterceptor.preHandle(StaticContentInterceptor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:148)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)][1]][1]
```

Comment: The error seems quite straightforward. The most likely explanation is that it really does not exist for the publication id and path that you're specifying. Have you tried to retrieve the binary using the GraphQL API, e.g. through Graphiql or Postman?

Comment: @Quirijn I have tried to check the binary in the broker database and it exists I don't know how to retrieve it using postman if u can give me some hints that will be helpful. thanks

Comment: The graphql query got mangled in the comment, so I posted it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this GraphQL query?

```
query bc {
  binaryComponent(namespaceId: 1, url: "/en/images/137005-e346c079-2fdc-438b-8403-e8abd3da82c0.json", publicationId: 10) {
    id
    variants (first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          ... on BinaryVariant {
            downloadUrl
            path
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Send this to the address of the public content API (ending with /cd/api). If oauth is enabled, you will need to request a token first and add an Authorization header.

Comment: Hi Quirjin Thanks for your reply i ran the query and i got below response

{"data":{"binaryComponent":null}}

Comment: So the binary really does not exist in the broker, it seems. Are you sure you are looking in the correct database? And can you share the sql query and its results?